# Best way to implement Auto save of the input value in Angular 2

Tags: angular, autosave

In my angular 2 application, I need to update database as per any change in an input tag value on UI screen.

I need to update this change in such a way that:
1. For the application end user, it seems like the input value has been auto saved. 
2. My application page has refresh functionality which refreshes the page automatically every 30 seconds using API hits.

What will be the proper approach to implement the auto save functionality so that it doesn't clash with the application's refresh functionality that is **user is making the changes at 29th second, and if the page refresh at 30th second, we need to preserve the data which user was entering**?

As per my understanding, to make a call to database on every keystroke in input tag is a very costly process.

Please suggest some useful and efficient approach.

Comment: You could save either on the `onblur`event for input fields or as part of the page refresh call?

Comment: Making call to database not always works, some input fields use the form controls. Please clarify your specific problem add code that you have written and errors if you have one.

Comment: @NathanFoss I am currently using blur event for saving data but how to deal with the scenario when the page is refreshed in middle while user is entering the data.

Comment: Are these the only possible approach, or is there any other work around for this.

Answer (score 2):

You could publish changes to a `BehaviourSubject` and delay each emission so your client doesn't make too many request.

Form.html

```
<input (change)="captureChange($event.target.value)"/>
```

Logic.ts

```
public $changeValues : Subject = new BehaviourSubject();

captureChange(val){
  this.changeValues.next(val)
}

ngOnInit(){
  $changeValues
    .debounceTime(/** some time you wish to delay by*/)
    .subscribe(val => autosave(val))
}
autosave(){
  /**

  Make HTTP Request


  **/
}
```